# Discord Bot (JDA) Rate Limit

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda, rate-limiting

I read somewhere that you can only modify 2 channels every 10 minuntes, but is this also the case with the messages that you send or can you only perform an operation like change / send / create twice every 10 min?

And what's the difference between `.queue();` `.complete();` and `.submit();`

Thanks in advance: D

Comment: This is the Link where I read that you can only modify 2 channels every 10 minutes: https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/issues/1306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rate limits change depending on the action you're performing. [Rate Limits](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits)

For `.queue()`, `.complete()`, `.submit()` view the documentation [here](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/) (Point #7).

Answer (score 1):

Rate-limits usually refer to changing the name/topic of a channel, or creating/deleting channels.
But limits can be also applied for adding reactions or even sending messages, to prevent abuse/spam (you can also notice if you spam in your own discord server).
From the Discord documentation: "Routes for controlling emojis do not follow the normal rate limit conventions. These routes are specifically limited on a per-guild basis to prevent abuse. This means that the quota returned by our APIs may be inaccurate, and you may encounter 429s."

If you are creating a bot that adds emotes on a regular basis, you might want to set a small timeout between such actions, otherwise the bot will get rate limited and will only resume after a quite long period of time.

To solve this, I added a boolean that only gets reset after the queue action of adding the last emoji is complete. It's a hacky solve, but does the job.